# Tab in Emacs-helm (anything) does not autocomplete with current best match

Tags: emacs, emacs24

While trying to autocomplete a file (e.g. to open a file with <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>) Emacs-helm shows a list of possible candidates.

If I then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (which I would hope it would help me choose the first/closest match), I get the following in the minibuffer:

[image]

It looks like the minibuffer gets confused with escape characters, and it does not choose the file that I actually want to open (the top choice).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Helm requires this conceptual jump from the default Emacs completion, which is not so obvious:

> You don't need to press a key to complete.  The completion buffer refreshes
>   with new results after every input.

This is called "incremental" completion.

The normal <kbd>tab</kbd> functionality is not needed in "incremental"
completion.  So tab was rebound to `helm-select-action`, which allows you to
choose an alternative action with the selection.  But there is only one action
in `read-file-name`.

The error you're seeing could be clearer though, I've filed this [issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/117) on github.

Additionally, note Helm treats each space separated term as a filtering
regular expression.  So, pressing <kbd>space</kbd> <kbd>foo</kbd> will filter
the current list down to those that contain foo in the name.