# How to restore anything-like behavior for TAB autocomplete in helm?

Tags: emacs, emacs-helm

A related question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537428/tab-in-emacs-helm-anything-does-not-autocomplete-with-current-best-match). But the answer is to get used to the new way autocomplete works in helm. I cannot get used to it, here's why.

Say, I want to open a file `/home/user/work/f.txt`. I do <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd>, it takes me to current dir, say `/current/dir/`. I hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and notice that autocomplete won't let me delete `/`. Ok, turn off autocomplete with <kbd>C-Backspace</kbd>. Then kill the line <kbd>C-a</kbd> <kbd>C-k</kbd> and start typing. Notice that autocomplete doesn't work, turn it back on <kbd>C-Backspace</kbd>. Normally I would type the part that I know is probably unique, e.g. `/hom` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Not here. As soon as I type `/ho`, autocomplete resolves it to `/home/`, but since I type fast, I end up with `/home/m`, and continue typing now meaningless characters until I notice it. Chances are, by that time I got autocompleted into directories that I had no intent of going.

So I have to constantly watch what autocomplete is doing, rather than rely on what I type and only checking suggested completions when I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I also find myself descending into wrong directories due to occasional typo, and then having difficulty going up a level -- evil autocomplete won't let you fix the situation with a couple of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>s.

This interaction of autocomplete behavior and the removal of <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality completely upsets my work, so much that I decided to ask this question. I am looking to either:

1. restore the old functionality
2. learn how to use autocomplete in a meaningful way, or
3. configure helm's <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> to behave more like a linux command line

Please help.

Comment: I wouldn't stick with helm if I had as much trouble with it as you describe.
I've had zero problems with ido: there's just `C-m` to accept directory and `C-j` to open.
Well, also `C-SPC` to narrow, but it's rarely needed.

Comment: @abo-abo: helm is invaluable for `M-x` command lookup. Also I really liked `anything`. Pretty much everything about it was great.

Comment: Is it better than  `https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex` at commands?

Comment: Also, I don't see why you can't just both, specifically ido for files and buffers, and
smex for functions and helm for whatever's left.

Comment: I'll try smex. No reason not to use it. I did not have a chance to discover it because `anything` just worked.

Comment: Regarding the first part of this: I don't know about Helm, but in vanilla Emacs, from that `/current/dir/` prompt, you could just start typing `/home/user/work/f.txt` without deleting anything -- i.e. `/current/dir//home/user/work/f.txt` or indeed `/current/dir/~/work/f.txt` and Emacs recognises that you've started a new path. As long as the old path ends with `/` you can just start typing a new absolute path. For the rest, given that Helm is promoted as a replacement for Anything, it seems awfully strange if the behaviour isn't at least optionally compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some `ido` tricks if you want to start using it.
Let me know if `helm` is better, perhaps I'll switch over.
I tried once shortly, but didn't like it.

#### Basic setup:

This will give you `ido-find-file on <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>.

```
(ido-mode)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

#### Smex setup:

Install from https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex.

```
(require 'smex)
(global-set-key "\C-t" 'smex)
```

#### Switch buffers with ido:

```
(global-set-key
 "η"
 (lambda()(interactive)
   (when (buffer-file-name)
     (save-buffer))
   (ido-switch-buffer)))

(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-η")
 (lambda()(interactive)
   (let ((ido-default-buffer-method 'other-window))
     (ido-switch-buffer))))
```

#### Tricks:

```
;; 1
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (define-key dired-mode-map "j" 'ido-find-file)))

(add-hook
 'ido-setup-hook
 (lambda()
   ;; 2
   (define-key ido-file-dir-completion-map "~"
     (lambda ()(interactive)
        (ido-set-current-directory "~/")
        (setq ido-exit 'refresh)
        (exit-minibuffer)))
   ;; 3
   (define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "η" 'ido-next-match)
   ;; 4
   (define-key ido-buffer-completion-map (kbd "C-p")
     'ido-fallback-command)
   ;; 5
   (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-.") 'smex-find-function)
   (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-,") 'smex-describe-function)))
```

1. Quick open file from dired.
2. Move to home directory one key faster (i.e. `~` instead of `~/`).
3. Cycle buffer candidates with the same key that shows the candidates (a la `C-TAB` in Firefox).
4. Useful to have a fall back when you want to create a file-less buffer (ido will try
   select an existing buffer unless you fall back).
5. Useful to jump to function definition/documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want TAB completion of directories and file names, map `helm-execute-persistent-action` to the TAB key:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```

See also the [answer to "How can I change emacs helm-find-file default action[...]"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27652821/65889).