# How can I change emacs helm-find-file default action on directory to be go inside the directory instead of open in in dired?

Tags: emacs, emacs-prelude, emacs-helm

I am using emacs prelude.

I recently decided to switch to helm from ido.

So I enabled `helm` and `helm-everywhere` in emacs prelude,

Everything works perfectly, except the default behavior of `helm-find-file`

In Ido, I could hit `ret`to go down the selected directory, but I have to hit `right` or `c-j` in helm. 
Also, `helm-find-files` would list `.` and `..` at the very top for every directory. 
This means in ido, I can just hit `ret` `ret` `ret` until I get to the final destination if there aren't many directories along the path.

But in helm, I had to type some chars, hit `c-j` type at least 1 char, hit `c-j` and so on. 
I cannot even hit `c-j` continuously.

I don't want to switch back to ido because I really love helm's grep feature in find-file.

Is there anyway I can change the default order to have it maybe list `.` and `..` at the bottom and `ret` to enter directory instead of open dired?

Answer (score 10):

The function you're looking for is     (helm-execute-persistent-action), which is bound to     C-z by default. Some people like to switch this with     tab:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z") 'helm-select-action)
```

You can bind it to ret if you like, but it won't open files the way you expect it to.

As for your other question, I don't know if helm has a way to set the default selection position, but to select the first item from the top you could do something like this:

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-j")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (helm-move-selection-common :where 'edge :direction 'previous)
    (helm-move-selection-common :where 'line :direction 'next)
    (helm-move-selection-common :where 'line :direction 'next)
    (helm-execute-persistent-action)))
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one works great, but the second one always open the third item in list.  Also, I tried helm-adaptive-mode but it does't seem to work with helm-find-file

Comment: By first item I meant the first item that isn't /. or /.. Is that what you meant by getting to the final destination with ret ret ret?

Comment: @nivekuil would you be able to help with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175154/emacs-ow-can-i-helm-find-with-default-directory-pre-specified  ?

Comment: See here http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/how-do-i-make-pressing-ret-in-helm-find-files-open-the-directory/7896#7896

Comment: To make TAB work in a terminal you also need `(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)`. See: http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html